# Adding x number of items to each page : Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, python-3.6

Given a value of `x`, I need to display `x` items on each page.

For eg:
I have a list of `10 items`. Given `x = 3`
I need to display `3` items on `page1`, `3 on page2`, `3 on page3` and `1 on page4`
value of `x` can be `odd` or `even`.

Stuck on how to break or start a new list for the second iteration.

Comment: Show your code or it didn't happen

Answer (score 0):

Something like below will be of help:

```
a=20 #Actual value holder
x=3  #the 'x' you need
rem_value=a%x
quot=int(a/x)

for y in range(quot):
  print(str(x)+" in page "+str(y+1))
  print('\n') 

if(rem_value)>0:
  print(str(rem_value)+" in page "+str(quot+1))
```

*> Output: (when 20 in input)

3 in page 1
3 in page 2
3 in page 3
3 in page 4
3 in page 5
3 in page 6
2 in page 7*

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to put the same effort into explaining, that you put into attempting

```
x = 3
l = [i for i in range(10)]
l1 = [l[i:i + x] for i in range(0, len(l), x)]
```